# Having two kinds of graphics in same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I'm experimenting with ggplot's port for Python. I can do very basic graphics without too much trouble, but it gets really complicated for me when trying some more fancy.

In this case, I want to plot 3 variables A, B and C at the same time along 'x', which can be done with the simple code below. However, I'd like to display a 4th variable (called 'Back') in the background of the display, as a series of rectangular shaped colours (using a colour gradient of sort).
Something that could look a little bit like this admitibly bad photoshop mockup : [image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/euqek8e6nebmau6/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202013-12-02%2014.29.16.png]

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this kind of graphic with ggplot for python?

If it could help answer the question, here is the xls file containing the data: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/B.xls

And here is the code:

```
from ggplot import *
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels

xl = pd.ExcelFile('B.xls')
df = xl.parse("sheet1")

df_lng = pd.melt(df[['x', 'A', 'B', 'C','Back']], id_vars='x')
print ggplot(aes(x='x', y='value', colour='variable'), data=df_lng) + geom_line()
plt.show(1)
```

Oh, and here is a post that I *think* could help do the trick. This was done in R though... https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3866629

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the R code to do this. Don't know how to do it with Python, but it appears that this would be similar.

```
ggplot(aes(x=x), data=df_lng) + geom_line(aes(y=value, colour=variable), size=1.3) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill=factor(Back), xmin=x, xmax=x+1, ymin=0, ymax=max(value)*1.07), alpha=.1) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(guide="none")
```

Comment: I believe you want the geom_rect layer below. Also, ymin=-Inf ymax=Inf is easier

Comment: It looks like geom_rect doesn't work in the python port yet (or does it?). I'm trying the snippet in R, but can't get the data melted like in my python code. How does it work in R?

Comment: I used `df_lng <- melt(df, id.vars=c("x", "Back"))`

Comment: Great, thanks Shadow and Baptiste, this works great in R at least! (I find that using ymin=-Inf and ymax=Inf works for me, by the way)

Comment: `geom_rect` is currently not implemented. I opend a bug about this: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/171